# SSH - Permission denied (publickey) - doesn't work in case of one node

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I have 3 nodes: node A, B and C. A wants to connect to B and C via ssh. B and C are identical servers. A can connect to B but cannot to C.

```
ssh user@node
```

The error I see:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've tried:

- The ownership settings on the ida_rsa and the authorized_keys files are correct and are the same on server B and C
- The /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is also identical on both nodes
- I can `telnet` to both node B and C via port 22 so it's not a firewall issue either

What have I missed? What else should I check?

So far I fail to see what forbids me from connecting to node C.

Comment: Have you got the ssh connection logs for us? Increase verbosity in the sshd_config file if there isn't enough there to go on.
The SSH logs are at AUTHPRIV level and stored in `/var/log/secure` on most systems.

Comment: Did you make sure the correct publickey is installed?

Comment: `id_rsa` is the private key. What's it doing on B and C?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who stumbles upon this topic, I've found the root of my issue. I'm writing this down because I haven't found a discussion where this solution was raised.

- in the sshd_config file the user was not prompted for any password: `PasswordAuthentication no`
- however the user was password protected in general on node C, but not on B

B node:

```
# passwd --status user
user LK 2017-09-27 0 99999 7 -1 (Empty password.)
```

C node:

```
# passwd --status user
user LK 2019-04-03 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
```

Solution:

```
# passwd -d user
Removing password for user user.
passwd: Success
```

Now `ssh` works fine.

I've found the problem when I checked the `/var/log/messages` file:

```
Connection from X.X.X.X port 60408 on Y.Y.Y.Y port 22
User user not allowed because account is locked
input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Connection closed by X.X.X.X port 60408 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 0):

oK i resolved. The name to be used is not the hostname, but the username you use tu access to the desktop. Or you can use root, but in this case it must be activated at the sshd_config. Example john@ip-address